# Is it possible to use both New Relic and Azure Application Insights together in single Azure project?

Tags: azure, newrelic, azure-application-insights

My new relic seems to stop working when I published my cloud service with Insights including dependency and I was wondering why is this happening as I haven't changed anything on my new relic settings. I have just added new start up task under CSDEF file as shown here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/#dependencies

I'm just looking for an answer whether or not it is possible to use them together, and if yes what would be the problem on my side?

Answer (score 2):

Startup task that you've added installs AI Status Monitor that adds/modifies a registry entry 'COR_PROFILER' under the 'environment' key in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC.
I believe that New Relic might rely on the same entry being set to a different GUID (NewRelic's profiler GUID, not AI GUID).
Hence, whoever sets this setting the last to its own ID wins the "competition"...

If you skip the step to enable AI Dependency collection, they (NR and AI) might actually work together, but I never tried it myself.